# YouTube V3 LiveBroadcasts: list issue with service account credentials

Tags: youtube-data-api

I was trying to make list api call to get the list of upcoming live streams. But when I was using service account credentials the API is always responding with below status.

{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "message" : "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
    "reason" : "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://www.youtube.com/features"
  } ],
  "message" : "The user is not enabled for live streaming."
}

Please let me know if I have to assign any specific role in IAM for this particular service account to allow this API to work.